# Preventing sending error messages to email sender

Tags: php, email, parsing, mime

I'm piping my mails using a PHP script and the sender mail keeps receiving the error messages:

```
  pipe to |/home/USERNAME/public_html/emailparser.php
    generated by info@example.com
    local delivery failed
```

I read that adding -q to #!/usr/bin/php will silence, but it doesn't. Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Put `#!/usr/bin/php` as the first line of the script, so that the system knows that it should be using /usr/bin/php  to run your script.  Also, make sure that your script has executable permissions enabled for all users.

If that doesn't work, check your mail server delivery logs, and these should shed some light on what the problem is.